# Alter keywords searched in solr

Tags: search

I want to search phrase entered by user as

```
q="phrase"^21.0 OR phrase
```

On `localhost:8983/solr/admin/form.jsp`
it parses `"phrase"^21.0 OR phrase` perfectly! and return correct results

How can i do it in PHP. I am using Drupal 6.
Please help!!

If more information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="drupal" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
<str name="defType">dismax</str>
```

so the request handler was "default" hence query was parsed with deftype:dismax and dismax does not parse BOOLEAN operators in the query string.

I created a new HANDLER in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="sohail" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <bool name="omitHeader">true</bool>
```

Set `$params[qt] = "sohail";` in the MYMODULE_apachesolr_modify_query()

Now it works perfectly!